# How to get mathematica to give an exact answer rather than a numerical approx

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried `// Rationalize` but it just gave the same answer [image: error]

Please help

Comment: Use Maximize to get exact answer. Also, Rationalize[_,0] to force rationalization for any number.

Comment: @user18792 I tried rationalize[_,0] but it gave me {605021091/95662234, {t -> 80143857/51021164}} I the answer I was looking for was {2 Sqrt[10], {t -> \[Pi]/2}}. Any suggestions what went wrong?

Comment: Since Sqrt[10], which is exact answer is in not a rational number your cannot expect to obtain it with Rationalize. I only wrote last suggestion since your complained that rationalize returned the same answer. And the second argument of Rationalize forces rationalization even if good approximation (with existing precision) is difficult to find.

Comment: Please post your code instead of picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) is preferred when it works; however, when a numeric technique is required, [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html) can find a close approximation that is not necessarily rational.

```
{max, arg} = FindMaximum[Sqrt[4*Sin[t]^2 + 36 Cos[2 t]^2], t]

(* {6.32456, {t -> 1.5708}} *)

max /. r_Real :> RootApproximant[r]

(* 2 Sqrt[10] *)
```

And when you expect/suspect a rational factor of a known irrational value

```
arg /. r_Real :> Pi*RootApproximant[r/Pi]

(* {t -> π/2} *)
```

Answer (score 10):

Making use of `Maximize` and the periodicity, we succeed with it.

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[4*Sin[t]^2 + 36 Cos[2 t]^2], t > -Pi && t <= Pi}, t]
```

> `{2 Sqrt[10], {t -> \[Pi]/2}}`